# How to create .mp3 files in my iPad?

Tags: ios, mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recording mp3 instead of caf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399019/recording-mp3-instead-of-caf-file)

I wonder if any can help me with my issue.

I have found the way to save my voice in the iPad. But so far I have created only .caf files. Can I create .mp3 files??

Thanks in advance.
I am attaching my code:

```
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], AVNumberOfChannelsKey, [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVAudioRecorder audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];

    if (error){
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
        [audioRecorder record];
    }
```

Comment: You ... really need to figure out SO formatting better: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: See also [iOS: Create an MP3 on device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145623/ios-create-an-mp3-on-device)