# Voice over MP3 - iPhone, iOS

Tags: iphone, mp3, record, voice

How can I implement a function that will record users voice over MP3 file?
Is there any tutorial you know of online?

I don't have any code and I will get a lot of rage here, but I'm stuck and I need help.
I searched for 2 hours and found nothing.

Comment: I have created my own sample [Download here](https://github.com/ioslovers/ATTabandHoldAudioRecord) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0fmbJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, there is **NO** direct way to record MP3(Maybe you can consider record to one format and convert it to MP3, but seems this is also not simple) file. Refer to these questions:

[iPhone App : recording audio in mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10553363/1548523)

[Recording mp3 instead of caf file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9399313/1548523)

[iOS: Record audio in other format than caf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11118966/1548523)